# How is PHP so high on this benchmark if it's said not to be as scalable as other frameworks?

Tags: database, scalability, benchmarking, web-frameworks

http://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/#section=data-r5

This benchmark shows PHP consistently on the top 5 of several measurements. This contradicts the consensus that it does not scale as well as frameworks/languages such as http-kit, node.js and go. What is happening there?

Answer (score 1):

I think this benchmarks are always assuming that you have a perfect structure with a perfect code. We all know that there is no perfect world and that php is scalable if your system is well designed and coded . 99% of the not cases that you find scalability problems are due to coding and technical architecture than the used technology. 
Is php scalable ? Hell yes. Look at facebook.

Off course there are other technologies that are supposed to be more scalable but it also depends of the problem at hands

Answer (score 1):

One thing they don't mention is secondary resource usage: they show how long it takes, but not the CPU/memory consumption required to achieve those results. Go is as fast or faster in most of those benchmarks, but will use only a small fraction of the memory.

Answer (score 1):

PHP was one of the first languages designed to create dynamic HTML content. Its free, very easy to use, and bring a lot of extensions with it that allow you to do virtually anything a website can do without need to buy third party modules (a very common practice in ASP).

Naturally this made PHP the most popular language for websites there is, and despite its younger competitors bring better scalability solutions, it won't affect its popularity so easily. Many giants use PHP, including Facebook that insisted so much in using PHP that designed its own scalability solution for it.